# Remove Metadata from Moviefiles with bash script

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, plex

I have a movie library and wanted to remove all metadata saved in any movie file. Is there a bash batch script, that removes them automatically, so that I don't have to check for every existing file? Because some of them have metadata like title and others don't. I've seen, that FFMPEG can do it, but has to copy the video and audio stream. Is there a better and faster solution?

Comment: Like he is doing it here on windows, but do it on Linux automated:
http://blog.ultimateoutsider.com/2017/06/solution-plex-media-server-keeps.html

Comment: Are you asking for help with the ffmpeg command or with the bash script or both? If both, are you wanting to convert all files in a directory? Are there subdirectories that need to be dealt with too?

Comment: @llogan mhhh soo I‘m looking for a solution...so I‘ve found an FFMPEG Command for it, but it will copy the audio and video stream, which is not very effective. The best solution is to „just“ remove the metadata. So I‘m looking for that „command“. And yes, my folder structure is:

movies/[MOVIETITLE]/MOVIETITLE.extension

Comment: I believe that you can't avoid rewriting the entire file.  When you change some of the metadata, you'll be changing the location of various parts of the file and the file has to update the pointers to those locations.

Comment: @TobiasHeinze Not possible with ffmpeg. It can't edit files in place. It must output a new, separate file.